# check if a number lies in between two values

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

I have this file

```
427 A   C   A/C 12
436 G   C   G/C 12
445 C   T   C/T 12
447 A   G   A/G 9
451 T   C   T/C 5
456 A   G   A/G 12
493 G   A   G/A 12
```

I wanted to read the first column and find all other ids which are differences less than 10.

```
427 A   C   A/C 12  436
436 G   C   G/C 12  427,445
445 C   T   C/T 12  436,447,451
447 A   G   A/G 9   445,451,456
451 T   C   T/C 5   445,447,456
456 A   G   A/G 12  451,447
493 G   A   G/A 12
```

The last column should be like the above. All id's which are + or - 10 bases apart from that specific id. For example for 436, the boundaries are {426 - 446} other id's which are in that range are 427 and 445 so i displayed them in 6th column..

Comment: So you started doing this in perl, sed or awk, and got stuck at what point?

Comment: this was actually part of a big code and i am struck at this point. being a novice i am not sure how i can achieve this. i was able to do this in excel but as i want to automate this and keep as a part of my other code. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'dataFile.txt' or die $!;
chomp( my @data = <$fh> );
close $fh;

my @IDs = map /(\d+)/, @data;

for (@data) {
    my ($id) = /(\d+)/;
    print "$_\t"
      . ( join ',', grep { abs $id - $_  < 11 and $id != $_ } @IDs )
      . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
427 A   C   A/C 12  436
436 G   C   G/C 12  427,445
445 C   T   C/T 12  436,447,451
447 A   G   A/G 9   445,451,456
451 T   C   T/C 5   445,447,456
456 A   G   A/G 12  447,451
493 G   A   G/A 12
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file.txt{,} | column -t
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
FNR==NR {
    array[$1]++
    next
}

{
    n = asorti(array,sort)

    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {

        if (sort[i] <= $1 + 10 && sort[i] >= $1 - 10 && $1 != sort[i]) {
            line = (line ? line "," : line) sort[i]
        }
    }

    print $0, line

    line = ""
}
```

Results:

```
427  A  C  A/C  12  436
436  G  C  G/C  12  427,445
445  C  T  C/T  12  436,447,451
447  A  G  A/G  9   445,451,456
451  T  C  T/C  5   445,447,456
456  A  G  A/G  12  447,451
493  G  A  G/A  12
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]++; next } { n = asorti(array,sort); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) if (sort[i] <= $1 + 10 && sort[i] >= $1 - 10 && $1 != sort[i]) line = (line ? line "," : line) sort[i]; print $0, line; line = "" }' file.txt{,} | column -t
```